# adding multiple filter selections to sheet in Qlik

Tags: qliksense

I'm a newbie in Qlik Sense. I would like to make a multiple valued filter as default selection when the sheet is loaded to any user. How can I do this?

My Data (Users)

```
User1
User2
User3
Demo
```

My default filter should have the following selection: User1, User2, User3

I would like to make a multiple valued filter as default selection when the sheet is loaded to any user. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of options:

### Apply bookmark on app open

You can use Qlik's bookmarks ability. Bookmarks can be used to save specific selections (instead of making them every time). [Create bookmark](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense/August2022/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/Bookmarks/create-bookmark.htm) documentation

Bookmark can also be made `default`. This will enforce Qlik to apply the bookmark when the app is open. [Set default bookmark](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense/August2022/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/Bookmarks/set-default-bookmark.htm)

- select the required values
  [image: selected values]
- open bookmarks menu
  [image: bookmarks menu]
- give the bookmark a name
  [image: bookmark modal]
- once the bookmark is created - right click on the bookmark and select `Set as default bookmark`
  [image: set default]
- save the app
- every time the app is open this specific bookmark will be applied

### Sheet actions

The other option (that can also involve bookmark) it to set an action when the sheet is activated [Setting sheet action](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense/August2022/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/Sheets/setting-sheet-actions.htm)

- navigate to the desired sheet
- enter in edit mode and expand the `Actions` property
  [image: actions property]
- choose your action - either apply bookmark or directly list the values that have to be selected

  [image: actions]